# How to manipulate select option dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to add option to select dynamically through JavaScript by clicking on a button. I want to make sure if it has an option already present then it add at n+1 option place only.

```
<select name="select">
 <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
 <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
 <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<button onclick =addvalue()>clickme</button>enter code here
function addvalue()
 {
  var e=document.getElementById('select');
  var i =0;
  var abc = true;
  while(abc)
  {
   if (e.options[i].innerText==null)
   {
    abc =false;
   }
   i++;
 }
 alert(i);
}
```

But this is throwing an error that `e.options[i].innerText` is null or not an object. I will replace alert with code for adding option later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> e.options[i].innerText is null or not an object

because there's no `options[i]` when `i >= options.length`. Check if it exists:

```
function addvalue()
 {
  var e=document.getElementById('select');
  var i =0;
  var abc = true;
  while(abc)
  {
   if (!e.options[i] || e.options[i].innerText==null)
   {
    abc =false;
   }
   i++;
  }
  alert(i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eMQzC/

It will alert **4**, which I'm not sure is what you want to get. `i` is incremented once after `abc` was set to `false`.

I think you may not need that while loop at all.

```
function addvalue()
 {
  var e=document.getElementById('select'), i = e.options.length;
  alert(i);
}
```

This will alert `3`, as it is the number of options in your select.

Answer (score 1):

You're using document.getElementBy**Id**('select');, but specified a **name** of select. Change 'name' to 'id', and you should be good, although I'd recommend something a bit more descriptive than "select" :)

e.g. 
from `<select name="select">`  to `<select id="select">`

Comment: I got that it's a mistake but even correcting is throwing same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using getElementByID API you need to get an id.
add an 'id' attribute to the select and you get your element.

Use the developer tool of the browser (chrome - f12) to debug your code.
If you add debugger; statement it will stop automatically.